# Podemos conjugar um verbo reflexo com o indeterminante do sujeito "se"?

Tags: sujeito-indeterminado

Vejamos com um exemplo.

> O pessoal, em Braga reza, no Porto trabalha, em Coimbra estuda, e em Lisboa diverte-se.

Agora se substituirmos o **o pessoal** pelo indeterminante do sujeito **se**, o que é que se faz em Lisboa?

> Em Braga reza-se, no Porto trabalha-se, em Coimbra estuda-se, e em Lisboa diverte-?????

Diverte-se-se? Para além da questão (da falta de) estética *diverte-se-se* é gramatical? (Podemos dizer *goza-se*, mas não é isso que vem ao caso.)

Comment: Não me soa mal dizer simplesmente «e em Lisboa diverte-se».  Sei que no castelhano há uma regra explícita de suprimir um dos ses nestos casos e imagino que o português teria parecida, não é?  (não tenho uma gramática portuguesa na minha escrivaninha para consultar ou tentaria achá-la)

Comment: @guifa A mim não me soa muito bem "em Lisboa diverte-se" (quem é que se diverte?)... Para mim _Em Braga reza-se ... e em Lisboa uma pessoa diverte-se_. E definitivamente, _se-se_ não é uma opção.

Comment: @Artefacto o meu ouvido é obviamente muito influenciado pelas outras línguas ibéricas haha por isso só escrevi um comentário e não uma resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Não**, porque não é possível a coocorrência de dois pronomes clíticos com o mesmo som, mesmo que tenham funções sintáticas distintas.

*Uma pessoa diverte-se* não pode ser reformulado como **diverte-se-se*, com um *se* anticausativo, e um *se* impessoal. Da mesma forma, *apresentei-me a mim próprio* não pode ser reformulado **apresentei-me-me*, em que o primeiro *me* é dativo e o segundo acusativo. Esta última forma é ainda excluída pelo facto de não ser possível integrar clíticos que não têm formas distintas para o acusativo e para o dativo (por exemplo, não podemos reformular *entregámo-nos a vocês* com **entregámo-nos-vos*).

Na discussão sobre este assunto, em que de resto me baseei acima, a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (2013, p. 2236), contém uma nota que compara o português com o italiano e que reproduzo aqui parcialmente por achar interessante:

> O português [...] não permite [...] a coocorrência entre *se* impessoal e *se* inerente ou *se* reflexo [...]. Outras línguas românicas, como, por exemplo, o italiano, comportam-se diferentemente. Assim, a frase **lava-se-se* é agramatical em português, mas a frase correspondente em italiano é possível: *ci si lava* (*ci* = impessoal; *si* = reflexo). Embora o pronome impessoal tenha normalmente em italiano a forma *si* (idêntica à forma do pronome reflexo), *si* (impessoal) pode ser convertido em *ci*, em italiano-padrão, por forma a evitar a sequência agramatical *si si* [...]. O português não dispõe de uma estratégia semelhante à do italiano-padrão, pelo que só é permitida a ocorrência de um único pronome *se* por domínio oracional.

Guifa interroga-se nos comentários se é possível em português o clítico *se* ter um significado duplo (*se* impessoal/nominativo e *se* inerente, anticausativo ou reflexo). Este tipo de fenómeno designa-se de ***haplogia sintática*** e ocorre de facto em português noutras circunstâncias. João Peres e Telmo Móia dão estes exemplos (*Áreas Críticas da Língua Portuguesa*, p. 101):

> Era melhor que eu te dissesse a verdade (do) que [que] te viessem outros contá-la.
>   Acabei de almoçar [com] com quem tu almoçaste ontem.

No entanto, o tipo de combinação que Guifa sugere é marginal em português. Afonso Miguel, na [sua tese de mestrado](http://www.clul.ulisboa.pt/files/telmo_moia/afonsomiguel2006.pdf), depois de defender a mesma tese que esta resposta (embora indique que a razão para não ser possível combinar dois clíticos *se* é discutível), tem isto a dizer sobre a haplogia (p. 50, ortografia original, citações e notas de rodapé omitidas, negrito meu):

> [V]erifica-se uma certa tendência entre os falantes (do português europeu) para usar verbos intrinsecamente pronominais em construções impessoais do tipo em causa. Nestes casos, verifica-se sistematicamente um fenómeno de haplologia sintáctica, sendo suprimida uma das duas partículas pronominais *se*. **A gramaticalidade das construções resultantes é, no entanto, duvidosa para a generalidade dos falantes**:
>
> ??Por vezes, **esquece-se** de que há muitas crianças que passam fome.
>
> Para ilustrar ocorrência do fenómeno de haplologia descrito no parágrafo anterior, recorri ao corpus CETEM Público. Após uma pesquisa limitada aos verbos *queixar-se* e *esquecer-se* (de), encontrei apenas o seguinte exemplo de haplologia:
>
> «Reconhece-se importância a quem grita mais alto e **esquece-se** de que quem grita mais alto é porque não se sente ouvido nem obedecido, ou não tem razão.»

O autor tem mais à frente um explicação alternativa para esta frase — pode tratar-se de uma confusão com uma forma não pronominal de *esquecer*.

Comment: A citação menciona que o doble ocorrência não é permitido, mas não diz nada sobre a possibilidade de ter um significado doble (é dizer, usar «diverte-se» com significado impessoal *e* reflexo)

Comment: @guifa Não encontrei nada a esse respeito, mas se essa estratégia existisse em português, seria estranho não a mencionar (e mencionar o que acontece em italiano). Isto corresponde à minha sensibilidade; para mim _diverte-se_ só é possível com sentido impessoal se existir um sujeito como "uma pessoa", realizado ou não: "O que é que uma pessoa havia de fazer aqui? Diverte-se!"

Comment: @guifa Encontrei informação relevante para a questão que levantaste.

Comment: bom encontro!  Também outra possibilidade (aparte de confusão pela forma não pronominal) poderia ser influência das línguas vizinhas (mas não sei como é no galego ou mirandês, mas é o normal no asturiano e no castelhano, esse último pode ter —ao mesmo tempo por «haplogia sintática»— três significados diferentes, pronominal inherente, dativo ético, e impessoal!)

Comment: Encontrei este exemplo de haplogia no [*Económico*](http://economico.sapo.pt/noticias/leica-nao-ha-duas-iguais_184120.html):  «Nessa altura, de alguma forma, chegou aos ouvidos de Ernst, Gunther e Ludwig, o seguinte ditado popular: "em Lisboa diverte-se; em Coimbra estuda-se; em Braga reza-se e no Porto trabalha-se"». Só confirma a opinião que eu tenho deles.

Answer (score 0):

não, simplesmente diverte-se.

Assim:

> Em Braga reza-se, no Porto trabalha-se, em Coimbra estuda-se, e em Lisboa diverte-se.

Percebe-se bem o contexto e o significado da frase. Parece mais uma expressão popular para designar o que se faz em cada cidade.