# É correto dizer - ou escrever - "apresentaram-te-nos"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronomes-oblíquos

Acredito que, se correto, seu uso na língua falada seja muito raro. Além do mais, existem formas mais simples de se dizer o mesmo: "apresentaram-te a nós", "tu foste apresentada a nós", etc.  Caso seja realmente gramatical, me parece um verbo muito sobrecarregado de pronomes oblíquos e soa muito estranho aos meus ouvidos. É correta essa formação?

Comment: C'um caráter, eu diria que não, pela resposta do Artefacto a esta [outra pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/podemos-conjugar-um-verbo-reflexo-com-o-indeterminante-do-sujeito-se).

Comment: @Jacinto O que seria "C'um caráter"?  Confesso que não existe por aqui.

Comment: É um expletivo (não acrescenta significado) eufemístico no meu idioleto. "C'um" é "com um".

Comment: Correção abaixo de 6 caracteres: tu *foste* (ou *vós* fostes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não. Como mencionei [nestoutra resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1549/249), não é possível usar simultaneamente dois clíticos que não têm formas distintas para o acusativo e para o dativo (i.e. clíticos da 1ª e 2ª pessoas).

Segundo a *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (vol. II, p. 2236):

> Os pronomes de primeira e segunda pessoa, que não apresentam formas morfofonologicamente distintas para o acusativo e o dativo, não podem formar entre si grupos clíticos. Por isso, a sua coocorrência numa mesma oração não é permitida. Assim, a partir de *entreguei-me completamente a ti* não é possível obter **entreguei-me-te completamente*, com o clítico *te* (dativo) substituindo a forma pronominal forte *ti*, complemento da proposição *a*. O mesmo se pode dizer de **entregámo-nos-vos*, a partir de *entregámo-nos a vocês*, e de outros casos semelhantes.

Se houver uma perífrase verbal, poderá ser possível fazer subir um dos clíticos e assim permitir a sua coexistência. Por exemplo:

> Eles ainda nos hão de apresentar-te.

Esta impossibilidade parece não ter existido no passado. Diz Evanildo Bechara na sua gramática:

> Nas demais combinações [de pronomes átonos], o português moderno prefere substituir o pronome átono objetivo indireto pela forma tônica equivalente, precedida da preposição *a*.
>
> Enquanto dizemos hoje *a mim te mostras* ou *te mostras a mim*, a língua de outros tempos consentia em tais dizeres:
>
> > “Porque assi te me mostras odiosa?” [JCR.1 apud SS.1, § 271].

onde *JCR.1* se refere a *Naufrágio de Sepúlveda* de *Jeronymo Corte-Real* (1598).

Comment: Eles adiantam alguma razão para a impossibilidade? Por exemplo, não se saber qual é o acusativo e qual é dativo?

Comment: @Jacinto Não. Essa é uma explicação possível, mas não cobre a impossibilidade de _se-o_ (e.g. _*mandou-se-o embora_, só possível nalguns dialetos).

Comment: Também não estava muito convencido dessa razão. Seria possível convencionar uma ordem. Lembrei-me que no inglês também se diz *give  me the book* mas não _*give me it_. Poderá em ambos os casos uma questão de não soar bem.

Comment: @Jacinto "give me it" está correto no inglês. Acho que a razão pode originar numa ordenantiga dos pronomes oblíquos. No espanhol por exemplo, seja a sua função, o te *sempre* vai antes do me : *te me acerco* e *te me acercas*. Se o verbo não é reflexivo há ambiguedade total. Então pode que no desenvolvido do português os falantes rechazassem a combinação.

Comment: @guifa Sim, descobri [aqui](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/is-it-incorrect-to-say-give-me-it) que *give me it* é comum nalguns dialetos. [O Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give+me+it%2Fgive+it+to+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28give%20me%20it%20/%20give%20it%20to%20me%29%3B%2Cc0) mostra-o com um frequência de 1% de *give it to me*; na realidade é menos ainda, porque a maioria das ocorrências são falsos positivos (e.g. *the gift he as kind to give me. It is...*)

Comment: @Jacinto http://linguistics-research-digest.blogspot.nl/2014/01/give-it-me_27.html

Comment: @Artefacto Muito interessante. Parece haver uma divergência entre língua escrita e falada. Eu vivi nas Midlands durante uns anos, e não me lembro de ouvir *give it me*. Só se eles diziam *give it me* e eu ouvia *give it to me*.

Comment: ( @guifa não se diz rechazar em português, só em espanhol. Podes usar rejeitar, ou recusar. HTH!)

Comment: @ANeves Obrigado, é uma das coisas que sei mas... ao ir duma para otra língua uso uma palavra da outra.  Hoje mesmo usei mais duma vez ficar no espanhol haha

Comment: @ANeves em português há o coganto _rechaçar_.

Comment: Wops, afinal há o [rechaçar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/recha%C3%A7ar) sim... Desculpa-me @guifa, :) do alto da minha minha vontade de ajudar acabei por dizer uma asneira!