# Na locução 'Deseja-se conformar-se com as novas leis vigentes.' apresenta agramaticalidade a vosso ver?

Tags: sintaxe, colocação-pronominal, pronomes-reflexivos

Li que é possível no caso de 'deve-se; costuma-se e pode-se' (nalguns casos, com 'querer') analisar as seguintes estruturas de duas formas:

(1) Podem-se perguntar asneiras. / (2) Pode-se perguntar asneiras.

Em 1. 'Podem-se perguntar' seria analisada como locução verbal de voz passiva pronominal equivalendo a 'Asneiras podem ser perguntadas'.
Em 2. O sujeito de 'pode-se' é a oração reduzida de infinitivo 'perguntarem..', o verbo perguntar por sua vez teria sujeito indeterminado. Equivalendo a 'É podido perguntarem asneiras.'
Como veem está análise?

O problema fica maior ao tentar colocar outro clítico na oração. Como no caso do título:

(3) Deve-se se conformar(-se) com as leis vigentes.

Aqui não haveria a possibilidade de duas análises 'Devem ser se conformados com as leis vigentes'(?), mas em 'É devido conformarem-se com as leis. não é tão mal. O primeiro clítico exerceria, então, a função de apassivador, já o segundo, de reflexo, pois imagine que a construção se dá num diálogo no qual o sujeito de 'conformar' é 'vocês'. (noutra construção seria indeterminador talvez? a depender do contexto (4)):

(4) Deve-se conformar-se com as leis vigentes. (É devido que se conforme com as leis vigentes).

Comment: Essa locução não me parece correta, podes corrigir? "Deve-se conformar", ou "devem-se conformar", ou "devem conformar-se", ou "deve comformar-se". Nunca "deve-se se conformar" (um _se_ a mais) nem "deve-se se comformarem" (um _se_ a mais e não-concordância de tempo do verbo comformar).

Comment: @ANeves, para ti, soa certo «devem-se conformarem-se»?

Comment: Além do cacófato 'se' e 'se' não parece haver algum empecilho gramatical. = É devido que se conformem com as leis vigentes.

Comment: No caso do sujeito agente de 'É devido' há um ocultamento que com 'conformar' meio que o realça.

Comment: @Schilive, para mim poderia ser "devem-se conformar-se", sem plural no "conformarem".

Comment: Mas o Artefacto esclareceu que isto é agramatical... 

Answer (score 1):

Em geral, a repetição de clíticos *se* com valores diferentes é proibida em português. Isto foi abordado [nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1549). Por isso, se quiseres dizer:

> Uma pessoa deve conformar-se com as leis vigentes.

Não podes reescrever a frase com *se* impessoal ou apassivante, como poderias em:

> Uma pessoa deve tratar os outros como eles querem ser tratados.
> Deve(m) tratar-se os outros como eles querem ser tratados.

Os exemplos que dás, contudo, são agramaticais por um motivo diferente. Os verbos *dever* e *poder* são verbos (semi)auxiliares. Há uma combinação com um verbo pleno que resulta numa *perífrase verbal*, um grupo verbal coeso que funciona em vários aspetos como se fosse um só verbo.

> (2) Pode-se *perguntarem asneiras.

Esta frase (2) é agramatical. Verbos auxiliares não se combinam com verbos plenos no infinitivo flexionado. As opções gramaticais são apenas (na minha ordem de preferência):

> - Podem perguntar-se asneiras.
> - Podem-se perguntar asneiras.
> - Pode perguntar-se asneiras.
> - Pode-se perguntar asneiras.

É precisamente por *poder* ser um verbo auxiliar que a subida do clítico (segunda e quarta frases) e a construção passiva pronominal (primeira e segunda) são admitidas.

Comment: @ludovic Acho impossível. desejar não funciona com partícula apassivadora assim. Além disso, Priberam diz que se for transitivo e pronominal, é sexual.

Comment: @Lambie Como assim 'sexual'? Minha análise, a princípio, havia sido 'desejar' com sujeito indeterminado. 
Alguém deseja conformar si mesmo às leis.

Comment: Teria que ser: Alguém deseja conformar-se às leis. O que parece ser um pouco estranho como ideia. Quem diria isso?

Comment: As duas análises acho que dariam na mesma, pois há indefinição de sujeito.. Agora entendi o que quiseste dizer com 'sexual'. Ainda sim na análise de voz passiva seria concebível, nesta acepção seria transitivo direto e o 'se' PA.  Equivalendo a Desejam conformar-se às leis.

Comment: "Quem diria isso?" 
De fato, há construções possíveis que não soem ao cacófato 'se' e 'se', mas pensei nesta possibilidade como realce ao sujeito indeterminado. De qualquer forma só achei a construção excêntrica e se analisar sintaticamente parece-me correta.

Comment: @ludovic Eu estava me referindo ao sentido. Rogue-se conformar-se às leis. :) Melhor, você não acha?

Comment: Ah sim, quanto ao sentido, se for pra analisar em uso não há como ser analisado o primeiro clítico de 'desejar' como PIS, em uso só dá, de fato, para analisar como voz passiva. Devido ao referente oculto do verbo 'desejar' (agente da passiva) nem me dei conta como seria em uso, fui presumindo ser indeterminado. Com esta construção, não tenho afinidade não :'( ; (seria PE?).

Comment: Acha que minha análise está correta? Talvez, tenha moldado um pouco ela, então vou explicar de novo: Deve-se conformar-se com as leis vigentes. (ignore alternância no verbo, rs.) 'Deve-se' voz passiva = É devido; Agente da passiva dá pra analisá-lo como oculto = todos, devido à ordem que o mesmo exprime; E, por fim, 'conformar-se' realçaria o agente da passiva oculto (todos/qualquer um).

Comment: @ludovic O meu único problema era com o verbo desejar. Acho que "deve-se" tambem funciona. :)